# difference between REGEXP_LIKE and normal like with wildcard in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Why I get different output for the below SQL queries. I thought they all mean one and the same, but actually they are not. what is the difference between them.

```
select distinct CITY from STATION where REGEXP_LIKE(lower(CITY), '^[^aeiou]') or REGEXP_LIKE(lower(CITY), '[^aeiou]$');

select distinct CITY from STATION where lower(CITY) like '[!aeiou]%' or lower(CITY) like '%[!aeiou]';

select distinct CITY from STATION where lower(CITY) not like '[aeiou]%' or lower(CITY) not like '%[aeiou]';
```

Comment: `like '[!aeiou]%'` means "match any value that starts with `[` followed by `!` followed by `a` followed by `e`  followed by `i` followed by `o` followed by `u` followed `]` and then can have any number of characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[TL;DR]** Your `LIKE` queries do not match a single character and a wildcard since the `LIKE` operator does not support regular expressions.

```
select distinct CITY
from   STATION
where  REGEXP_LIKE(lower(CITY), '^[^aeiou]')
or     REGEXP_LIKE(lower(CITY), '[^aeiou]$');
```

Will look for any city that starts or ends with a character that is not a vowel.

```
select distinct CITY
from   STATION
where  lower(CITY) like '[!aeiou]%'
or     lower(CITY) like '%[!aeiou]';
```

The `LIKE` operator does not support regular expressions; so this query is looking for a city that starts or ends with 8 character sub-string consisting of the `[` character then the `!` character and then the `aeiou` vowel characters and then the `]` character.

```
select distinct CITY
from   STATION
where  lower(CITY) not like '[aeiou]%'
or     lower(CITY) not like '%[aeiou]';
```

Again, the `LIKE` operator does not support regular expressions; so this query is looking for a city that either does not start with or does not end with the 7 character sub-string consisting of the `[` character then the `aeiou` vowel characters and then the `]` character.

If you want to use `LIKE` then:

```
select distinct CITY
from   STATION
where  (   lower(CITY) not like 'a%'
       AND lower(CITY) not like 'e%'
       AND lower(CITY) not like 'i%'
       AND lower(CITY) not like 'o%'
       AND lower(CITY) not like 'u%' )
or     (   lower(CITY) not like '%a'
       AND lower(CITY) not like '%e'
       AND lower(CITY) not like '%i'
       AND lower(CITY) not like '%o'
       AND lower(CITY) not like '%u' );
```

Answer (score 1):

These are not similar at all.  For instance, Oracle does not recognize character sets in `like` patterns.

So, this expression:  `lower(CITY) like '[!aeiou]%'` is looking for cities such as:

- `[!aeiou]this is a city name`
- `[!aeiou]???`

But it will not match a city name that consists only of letters, which is what I would expect city names to be.

Answer (score 0):

like `'[!aeiou]%'`  means matching string  starting with `[!aeiou]` following any string .
like `'%[!aeiou]'` means any string ending in `[!aeiou]`.Not like means not like staring or endding in `'%[!aeiou]'`.they are indeed different.
whereas `REGEXP_LIKE(lower(CITY), '^[^aeiou]') or REGEXP_LIKE(lower(CITY), '[^aeiou]$')` doesnot make any sense.